# Cant change single value in session array in Laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, session

This my method update for products. And cant to change qty of product. Data saved inside foreach, but nothing change out of this. I can't understand what the problem.

```
if (!session()->has('products')) {
            session()->put('products', []);

        }

        $products = session()->get('products');

        foreach ($products as $item) {
            if (isset($item[$product->id])) {
                $item[$product->id]['qty'] = 10;
                dd($products); // dd($item) - changes
                $request->session()->put('products', $products);
                return redirect()->back();
            }

        }


        session()->push('products', [
            $product->id => [
                'product' => $product,
                'qty' => 1
            ]
        ]);


        return redirect()->back();
```

As you can see there is dd($products) - so its not change. But if dd($item) so it has qty 10.

Answer (score 0):

I can solved this with next:

```
foreach ($products as $key => $value) {
    if (isset($value[$product->id])) {
        $value[$product->id]['qty'] = 10;
        $products[$key] = $value;
        $request->session()->put('products', $products);
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Just add a $key => $value and save it in $products[$key] = $value;